# match multiple types for template specialization resolution

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++11

*Briefly dismiss the fact that normal function overloading will serve this example better. It is meant only as a way to learn about template programming. Having said that, you are welcome to comment on the benefits/differences you'll get from using function overload, compared to function template specialization (although that might deserve a question of its own).*

---

Consider the following example:

```
template <typename T>
inline void ToString(T value, char* target, size_t max_size );

template <>
inline void ToString<float>(float value, char* target, size_t max_size)
{
   snprintf( target , max_size , "%f" , value);
}

template <>
inline void ToString<double>(double value, char* target, size_t max_size)
{
    snprintf( target , max_size , "%f" , value);
}
```

Is there a way to write only one of these specializations that match both `float` and `double` types?

Basically I envision writing a template specialization for a template type that will match both `float` and `double` (as sort of 'float or double' type matcher) but I'm not sure whether that is possible at all with C++. That said, I've seen unexpected template magic happen in front of my eyes before, so I think it's a good question to ask here.

Comment: If you want something that matches more than one concrete type, then that's partial specialization, which isn't allowed for functions.

Comment: hi @Kerrek, my understanding of partial specialization is that is about specializing a subset of the template parameters. I only have one template parameter in here. I don't follow how partial specialization is relevant here

Comment: Partial specialization means that the result is still a template, rather than a type. Consider for example `template <typename> struct X; template <typename T> struct X<T*>;` That's partial.

Comment: @Kerrek, how would you do it using a function object template?

Comment: Wrap the thing into a class, and specialize to heart's content.

Comment: @Kerrek, the part is not clear is what i should put in the specialization parameters. For your example on pointer types it would be T*, what would be in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a standard solution idiom:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>


// Helper class

template <typename T>
struct Printer
{
  static typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int>::type
  print(T x, char * out, std::size_t n)
  {
    return std::snprintf(out, n, "%f", x);
  }
};

// Convenience function wrapper

template <typename T> int print(T x, char * out, std::size_t n)
{
  return Printer<T>::print(x, out, n);
}

void f()
{
  char a[10];

  Printer<double>::print(1.2, a, 10);  // use helper class
  print(1.4f, a, 10);                  // wrapper deduces type for you
}
```

You'll get a compile-time error if you call either construction with a non-floating type. Beware though that this might erroneously work for long doubles, which require the `%Lf` format specifier; and also recall that floats get promoted to doubles when passed through variadic function arguments.